# Playa "no entries for this related channel"

Tags: playa

I'm using a Playa field within Matrix to specify related entries, in EE 2.5.5

If I set the "Channels" selection to -Any- everything works as expected and the entries to select from are displayed when you go to edit a content item.

If I change the "Channels" selection to any specific Channel, it displays "No entries for this related channel" when there are Open entries.

The themes folder URL is given with the full URL, and I have tried disabling the .htaccess as suggested at http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

what Playa version is this? 4.4 release introduced some bugs which will be fixed in a 4.4.1 release probably today, so this might be that.

Comment: It is 4.4. Will keep my eye out for the next release and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Updated to 4.4.1 and this has fixed the issue. Thanks :-)